# css fixed position not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, fixed

I'm doing a proof of concept site with paralax scrolling. I have 3 images on the right side of the page which link to anchors to navigate this single page site. If i put my #buttons div inside the parallax container, the buttons scroll and leave the links at the bottom of the page. If i leave them outside that div, they scroll even though ive set position to be fixed. It works perfect in FF, but not in chrome. All i need is a simple page with parallax scrolling, and three buttons on the right side of the page that persist in the same position on the screen regardless of where you have scrolled to. Why does it work in FF and not chrome? My code is below

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="A high performance parallax scrolling example." name="description">
<meta content="Parallax Scrolling Example" name="title">
<title>Parallax Scrolling Example</title>
<style>
body {
    padding: 45px;
    background-color: #010001;
}
p {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 30px;
    margin-right: 60px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
p span {
    background-color: rgba(1, 0, 1, .85);
}
a {
    color: #AFDBF2;
}
h1 {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-family: "Franklin Gothic Medium", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(178, 45, 0, .75);
    color: #EEE;
}
#parallaxContainer {
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
#parallaxContainer img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
#buttons {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:100px;
    right:10px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="parallaxContainer">
    <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_2mN0xk6r-Eo/TEh9lXrojWI/AAAAAAAAAuk/mDn5MDGetBE/s1600/0014.jpg">

</div>
    <div id="buttons">
        <div id="button1"><a href="#anch1"><img src="images/button.png"></a></div>
        <div id="button2"><a href="#anch2"><img src="images/button.png"></a></div>
        <div id="button3"><a href="#anch3"><img src="images/button.png"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">

<h1>Some Random Star Trek Quotes</h1>
<p><span>Captain Jean-Luc Picard: Duty. A starship captain's life is filled with solemn duty. I have commanded men in battle. I have negotiated peace treaties between implacable enemies. I have represented the Federation in first contact with twenty-seven alien species. But none of this compares with my solemn duty today... as best man. Now, I know, on an occasion such as this, it is expected that I be gracious and fulsome in my praise on the wonders of this blessed union, but have the two of you considered what you were doing to me? Of course you're happy, but what about *my* needs? This is all a damned inconvenience. While you're happily settling in on the Titan, I will be training my new first officer. You all know him. He's a tyrannical martinet who will never, *ever*, allow me to go on away missions. 
Data: That is the regulation, sir. Starfleet code section 12, paragraph 4... 
Captain Jean-Luc Picard: Mr. Data... 
Data: Sir? 
Captain Jean-Luc Picard: Shut up. 
Data: Yes, sir. 
Captain Jean-Luc Picard: [turning to the wedding guests] 15 years I've been waiting to say that. </p></span></p>
<br>
    </div>

<script src="http://www.kirupa.com/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<script>

var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || 
                            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
                            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                            window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

var transforms = ["transform", 
                  "msTransform", 
                  "webkitTransform", 
                  "mozTransform", 
                  "oTransform"];

var transformProperty = getSupportedPropertyName(transforms);

var imageContainer = document.querySelector("#parallaxContainer");

var scrolling = false;
var mouseWheelActive = false;

var count = 0;
var mouseDelta = 0;


//
// vendor prefix management
//
function getSupportedPropertyName(properties) {
    for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
        if (typeof document.body.style[properties[i]] != "undefined") {
            return properties[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function setup() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", setScrolling, false);

    // deal with the mouse wheel
    window.addEventListener("mousewheel", mouseScroll, false);
    window.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", mouseScroll, false);

    animationLoop();
}
setup();

function mouseScroll(e) {
    mouseWheelActive = true;

    // cancel the default scroll behavior
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    // deal with different browsers calculating the delta differently
    if (e.wheelDelta) {
        mouseDelta = e.wheelDelta / 120;
    } else if (e.detail) {
        mouseDelta = -e.detail / 3;
    }
}

//
// Called when a scroll is detected
//
function setScrolling() {
    scrolling = true;
}

//
// Cross-browser way to get the current scroll position
//
function getScrollPosition() {
    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop == 0) {
        return document.body.scrollTop;
    } else {
        return document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
}

//
// A performant way to shift our image up or down
//
function setTranslate3DTransform(element, yPosition) {
    var value = "translate3d(0px" + ", " + yPosition + "px" + ", 0)";
    element.style[transformProperty] = value;
}

function animationLoop() {
    // adjust the image's position when scrolling
    if (scrolling) {
        setTranslate3DTransform(imageContainer, 
                                -1 * getScrollPosition() / 2);
        scrolling = false;
    }

    // scroll up or down by 10 pixels when the mousewheel is used
    if (mouseWheelActive) {
        window.scrollBy(0, -mouseDelta * 10);
        count++;

        // stop the scrolling after a few moments
        if (count > 20) {
            count = 0;
            mouseWheelActive = false;
            mouseDelta = 0;
        }
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you upload your code in jsfiddle

Comment: You say it works in FF, but not in Chrome... what does "not working" mean? What is the behavior in Chrome?

Comment: sure, but what is that? my code there is complete, the only file you are missing is the 25x25 png called button.png

Comment: in chrome, the buttons scroll with the content. they dont stay fixed. if i move the button div into the #parallaxcontainer div, they move with the background but the links stay at the bottom of the page even though the images have moved

Comment: either way, the behavior is not static buttons. in FF, both ways it works correctly. they dont move, and stay married to the link

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net and http://jsbin.com are two sites that let you provide a working demo of your code in a form where the code is easily editable, e.g., like this: http://jsbin.com/AparitI/1/edit

Comment: Here's a fiddle for your usage - fiddles are generally the easiest way to get an answer no matter the depth of detail you give 
http://jsfiddle.net/fenderistic/ZYQBD/

Comment: thanks for that, so as you see even though the css sets position to be fixed, the buttons on the right are scrolling

Comment: I am not sure why exactly, but it seems to have to do with the fact that both the `buttons` and the `parallaxContainer` have `position: fixed`.  If you remove `position:fixed` from the `parallaxContainer`, the buttons stay fixed.

Comment: hmmmm yes they do, but now my content is starting below my bkgrnd img. how do i fix this? (sorry, im a back end guy, my css js and html or HORRIBLE lol)

Comment: if i reposition my #content container, after a few navigation clicks it is overtop the buttons...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fenderistic/ZYQBD/, I got rid of the parallaxcontainer all together and just adjusted the image and tweaked with the CSS some more. The buttons seem to remain static with the content overlapping the image.

Comment: thanks for all the help, almost there! i shortend the content for stack overflow, but there is actually about three pages worth, and the buttons are connected to the anchors on the page. it seems that with elliotM's revisions the archors arent working. please advise! thanks again!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZYQBD/3/

Comment: the button fuctions work in jsfiddle if you scroll right first, but it doesnt work without the scroll, and also in full screen mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a problem of **-webkit-transform: translate3d** because it is also not working in **opera** and **chrome** and both **opera** and **chrome** use webkit transform. On the other hand it's working on **IE10** and **FF** because they both use **transform: translate3d**

To make it easy you can use jquery library for your parallax effect like:
[skrollr.js](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/) or [stellar.js](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/) its easy and fast to create parallax.

Comment: it was a css issue. I added a z-index for the buttons, all is well. the completed code is at http://jsfiddle.net/ZYQBD/4/ thanks to all who helped!

Answer (score 0):

it was a css issue. I added a z-index for the buttons, all is well. the completed code is at jsfiddle.net/ZYQBD/4 thanks to all who helped!